# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth doesn't work properly UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, width, font-size

I have a `UILabel` defined below :

```
let disclaimerLabel : TTTAttributedLabel = {
    let label = TTTAttributedLabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    label.textColor =  UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(13)
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.text = "By logging in, you agree to our Privacy Policy and T&C."
    return label
}()
```

Now the problem is that on older phones such as iphone 4, the line of text does not fit within one line. I thought this would be solved by the `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` line, however instead of shrinking the text size appropriately, the label text appears like this : `By logging in, you agree to our Privacy Policy...` I cannot have this label have more than one line, therefore I cannot use `numberofLines = 2` or `label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail`

It is an absolute necessity in this case that **the whole text is visible in one line**. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It would really be helpful if you posted the code code of your label subclass

Comment: It's widely available on github, however it does not override any of those properties so the behaviour should be the same as of a `UILabel`

Comment: I set leading for it as equal to self.view with constant `self.view.frame.width *0.1` and same with trailing so basically 80% of screen width

Comment: Not home now, will post when i get back

Answer (score 0):

If your device is exactly iPhone 4 (so it runs iOS 7.0 or less), that's the point.

The property .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is available on iOS SDK 8.0 and later:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

If you need one line only for a label, use `.minimumScaleFactor` for ios lower than 8.0 instead.

Comment: It's an iPad 2 running the newest version of iOS available for it, I compared it to iPhone4 because the app is for iPhone and I'm just using my iPad for testing, but I have found that native iPhone only apps behave very similar on iPad 2 and on the iPhone 4,4s line